# Jenkins Build Token Root plugin: How to access the Type field in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Build Token Root plugin for triggering a project via script. As per the documentation, we can send an optional parameter `Type` while triggering a job like this:

> buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=RevolutionTest&token=TacoTuesday&Type=Mexican

I need to access this `Type` value inside the jenkins pipeline. How can I get that ?

So far I have tried to use

```
def causes = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()
sh 'echo Causes: ${causes}'
```

But that raises exception

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.Cause$RemoteCause
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the next topic can help you:

[NotSerializableException using Publish Over SSH in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824120/notserializableexception-using-publish-over-ssh-in-jenkinsfile)

Try something like it (put NonCPS function at end of your script):

```
sh 'echo Causes: ${getCauses()}'

@NonCPS
def getCauses() 
{
    return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()
}
```