# NotSerializableException using Publish Over SSH in Jenkinsfile

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use the *Publish over SSH* plugin inside a Jenkinsfile. However, I'm getting the exception `java.io.NotSerializableException` in the `createClient` method. This is my code:

```
def publish_ssh         = Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin")
def hostConfiguration   = publish_ssh.getConfiguration("${env.DSV_DEPLOY_SERVER}");

if( hostConfiguration == null )
{
    currentBuild.rawBuild.result = Result.ABORTED
    throw new hudson.AbortException("Configuration for ${env.DSV_DEPLOY_SERVER} not found.")
}

def buildInfo = hostConfiguration.createDummyBuildInfo();

def sshClient = hostConfiguration.createClient( buildInfo, new BapSshTransfer(
        env.SOURCE_FILE,
        null,
        env.DSV_DEPLOY_REMOTE_DIR,
        env.REMOVE_PREFIX,
        false,
        false,
        env.DSV_DEPLOY_COMMAND,
        env.DSV_DEPLOY_TIMEOUT as Integer,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        null
    ));
```

How can I get rid of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because some variables are not serializable.

From [doc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/f5c998378846209c2ceb37500f79d89c8da395ab/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables)

> Since pipelines must survive Jenkins restarts, the state of the running program is periodically saved to disk so it can be resumed later (saves occur after every step or in the middle of steps such as `sh`).

You may use `@NonCPS` annotation to do the creation,
use the

```
@NonCPS
def createSSHClient() {
// your code here.
}
```